# Call an IBAction existing from a remote server

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

Is it possible to call an IBAction from a remote server? It would make my life easier. I have a quiz app for the iPhone, and there I have an IBAction/arc4random consisting of the quiz questions and answers. My little problem is that I'm only updating the app with more questions every time I submit a new version. The rest of the app stays exactly the same. If I somehow instead could update an .m file somewhere on a server, I wouldn't have to submit a new version every 1000 questions. Is that even possible?

Thankful for answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a service like Parse.com you can build a database and just pull questions remotely similar to a web service.  That's what we're doing in our Trivia app.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO. You can't change or call a code in your app from the remote server. You can however create a database with your questions/answer and pull database from your server by the app.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. What kinds of databases are compatible with Xcode? Can the databases populate both UIIMageView and UITextView at the same time?

Comment: You can go either with CoreData or something else like SQLite... It's up to you. You will have to read the data and populate whatever you gave there.